# Add new method to Julia base operator

Tags: methods, julia

I would like to do some calculation before feeding the results to the string operator `^`. Currently I am doing the following:

```
"adsf" ^ Float64(6)
# MethodError: no method matching ^(::String, ::Float64)
```

The following is my attempt so far:

```
Base.^(x, y::Float64) = x ^ Int(y)
# syntax: "(x,y::Float64)" is not a valid function argument name
```

In general I think the function form is correct:

```
fu(x, y::Float64) = x ^ Int(y)
fu("adsf", Float64(6)) 
# "adsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsf"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the operator as a symbol

```
Base.:^(x, y::Float64) = x ^ Int(y)
```